When Can a Set of Surfaces Be Equipotentials?
The question on the title is the name of the section 5.0.0. of Smythe's book on electromagnetism. He explains this question very briefly, but i genuinely do not understand the argument. The page in question is:

I do not understand the condition. How can $\nabla^2 C/(\nabla C)^2$ not be a function only of $C$?

Because it could be a function of the position variables over the surface of $F$, which would mean that it is not in fact an equipotential.
